# XSLT set directory where result document ends up

Tags: xslt-2.0

The XSLT below creates result-documents as desired, with one exception: the result document ends up in the directory where the stylesheet was invoked from. I want the result document to be where it was found (i.e. overwrite itself with the transform version).

How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection(iri-to-uri('file:///home/paul/Text/?select=*.xhtml'))">
            <xsl:variable name="filename">
                <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:result-document indent="yes" method="xml" href="{$filename}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">    
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- transform templates removed -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using `href="{document-uri(.)}"` to use the full uri as the target rather than doing the tokenize to pull out the last segment.

Comment: @MartinHonnen you're right, it might, or it might not, depending on the processor.  If it were me I'd use something like `href="{document-uri(.)}.new"` anyway, so as not to overwrite the original if something goes wrong, and then use another procedure to rename the `.new` files once I know the whole XSLT has succeeded.